# React map not printing html data

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to output some JSON data as divs that arrive via GET request. The data arrives as expected and useEffect function prints it well in console. But nothing is being displayed at all. Here is the code below, if anyone has any idea how it works.

```
let Search = () => {
        axios.request(options).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data);
        setTracks(response.data.tracks.hits);
        }).catch(function (error) {
        console.error(error);
        });
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        tracks.forEach(element => {
            console.log(element);
        });
    },[tracks]);

    return (
        <>
        <input onChange={Event => {setTekstPretrage(Event.target.value)}} value={tekstPretrage}></input>
        <button onClick={Search}>Search</button>
        <div className='output'>
            {tracks.length > 0 && tracks.map(track => {
                <Track songName={track.title} artistName={track.subtitle} coverUrl=''></Track>
            })}
        </div>
        </>
    );
```

Comment: Any dev console errors? I see there is no check for `tracks` being null before using it and there's no `key` property, but not sure that matters. I don't see where the state is initialized so it might be fine / empty array, hard to tell.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `return` for arrow function if you add `{}`:

```
{tracks.length > 0 && tracks.map(track => {
  return <Track songName={track.title} artistName={track.subtitle} coverUrl=''></Track>
})}
```

or implicit return (with no `{}`):

```
{tracks.length > 0 && tracks.map(track =>
  <Track songName={track.title} artistName={track.subtitle} coverUrl=''></Track>
)}
```